# Combine 2 lists to create histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, histogram

I have 2 separate lists and I want to prepare a histogram. One list is the count of features and the other is the names of the features. The count should be on y-axis and names of the features should be on the x-axis.

I have prepared the 2 lists and combine them into one list and then created a dictionary, but when I am trying to create a pandas data-frame from the dictionary, then I am getting an error, hence I cant proceed. Please suggest what can be done to create the histogram plot of these 2 lists:

```
feature_list = [ 'camera',                                   
 'features',                                                                               
 'screen',                                                            
 'battery',                                                             
 'iPhone',                                                           
 'apps',                                                        
 'Bixby',                                                     
 'button',                                                         
 'feature',                                                         
 'pictures',                                    
 'design',                                     
 'sound',                                                        
 'size',                                                   
 'price',                                                        
 'display',                                                          
 'Camera',                                  
 'performance',                                                              
 'Battery',                                                            
 'bixby',                                                   
 'fingerprint',                                                              
 'charge',                                                         
 'speed',                                                      
 'charging',                                                           
 'software'] 

feature_count = [1606,           
1331,         
941,            
894,           
579,            
416,              
362,             
288,            
209,           
197,          
196,     
193,             
183,              
167,             
147,           
144,            
143,       
127,           
123,             
121,       
114,            
114,             
109,          
103]  

zipbObj = zip(feature_list, feature_count)
dictOffeatures = dict(zipbObj)
```

The expected result will be a histogram of these 2 lists.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`matplotlib` module](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html), specifically a `bar` plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

feature_list = [ 'camera',
 'features',
 'screen',
 'battery',
 'iPhone',
 'apps',
 'Bixby',
 'button',
 'feature',
 'pictures',
 'design',
 'sound',
 'size',
 'price',
 'display',
 'Camera',
 'performance',
 'Battery',
 'bixby',
 'fingerprint',
 'charge',
 'speed',
 'charging',
 'software']

feature_count = [1606,
1331,
941,
894,
579,
416,
362,
288,
209,
197,
196,
193,
183,
167,
147,
144,
143,
127,
123,
121,
114,
114,
109,
103]

plt.bar(feature_list, feature_count)
plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image: bar plot]

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your prompt reply, I am new to python and I want to create visualizations based on the data I provided. I created a data-frame from the same, but the area plot and boxplot does not give any insight, what other plots can be created from the same:

Comment: @SukritSen If by "data-frame" you mean something related to `pandas` then I believe there are many built in plotting options within the `pandas` module, but I haven't really used them so I don't know what the capabilities are. As for `matplotlib` you can easily make bar graphs, histograms (which are different than what I posted), pie charts, scatter plots, line graphs, and much more. There are even 3D plotting capabilities within `matplotlib`!! You can also combine everything I've listed to make very intricate and complex plots that perfectly meet your needs!